# Yii2: How to use backend web folders files in frontend

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have many images in backends web folder, I want to use those images in frontend how to get those files?

I need to display 1 (first) image which path is saved in database like Img1.jpg;img2.jpg;

```
    <?php
      foreach (explode(';',rtrim($row['images'],';'),1) as $key_img => $value_img)
 {
  ?>

<?php echo  Html::img('@backend/web'.'/'.$value_img);?>                  

<?php
 }
?>
```

Comment: `echo Url::to("@backend/web/$value_img");` in your loop paste the result here as well as the path to your image (name included).

Answer (score 1):

`<?= \yii\helpers\Html::img('@backend/web/images/your-image.jpg') ?>`

The src parameter, containing the backend alias, will be processed by [`Url::to()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to()-detail)

Check the docs for details on [`Html::img()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#img()-detail).

Comment: im not getting images

Answer (score 0):

Simply try:

```
<?= \yii\helpers\Html::img( Yii::getAlias('@backend'). '/web/images/your-image.jpg') ?>
```

Comment: actually its not a single image, im using foreach loop to get all the records from db and I need to display only first image from the path saved in db  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267036/yii2-how-to-display-images-from-backend-web-to-frontend-in-advanced-app

Comment: Can you please mention what error your are getting?