# Yii2: how to display images from backend/web to frontend in advanced app

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I need to display 1 (first) image which path is saved in database like `Img1.jpg;img2.jpg;`, I tried to seperate each path by using `explode`, getting all the images as array but not able to pick single path-

```
<div class="col-sm-6 masonry-item">
<a href="<?php echo Url::to(['site/roompage']); ?>" class="product_item text-center">
<span class="product_photo bordered_wht_border">

<?php
foreach (explode(';',rtrim($row['images'],';'),1) as $key_img => $value_img)
{
?>

<?php echo  Html::img('@backend/web'.'/'.$value_img);?>                  

<?php
}
?>

</span>
<span class="product_title"><?php echo $row['room_type']; ?></span>
<span class="product_price">Rs.<?php echo $row['rate']; ?></span>

</a>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: according to [common bootstrap configuration](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/config/bootstrap.php)  `@backend` gives you **path** not **url**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2: How to use backend web folders files in frontend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264463/yii2-how-to-use-backend-web-folders-files-in-frontend)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php

    // if you want only the first image is better 
    $my_image  = explode(';',rtrim($row['images'],';'),1);
    echo  Html::img('@backend/web'.'/'.$my_image[0]);

    }
  ?>
```

otherwise

```
  <?php

    // if you want all the image  

    foreach (explode(';',rtrim($row['images'],';')) as $key_img => $value_img)
    {
      echo  Html::img('@backend/web'.'/'.$value_img);
    }
  ?>
```

this because (explode(';',rtrim($row['images'],';'),1) return an array of two element (the first and the rest)

Comment: its not showing any images, in inspect element of the browser its showing error as `Not allowed to load local resource:`

Comment: I am not sure but just give a try to this. '@web/backend'

Answer (score 0):

The src parameter, containing the backend alias, will be processed by Url::to()

Check the docs for details on Html::img()

Comment: tried with `echo  Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@backend/web').'/'.$value_img[0]);`